# Magento Products Import Programmatically and and Multiple Storefronts

Tags: php, magento, import, mage

I have created a product import script which parse csv and import simple products. which is quite easy and there is lot of help available on it. The real problem is when i set them for different multiple storefronts.

```
 $websites = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->setLoadDefault(false);
 $websiteLookup = array();
 foreach ($websites as $website) {
    $websiteLookup[$website->getCode()] = $website->getWebsiteId();
 }
 $product->setWebsiteIds($websiteLookup)->save();
```

Question is, How could i set product titles and product descriptions for each storefront while adding product?

```
 $product->setDescription("DESCRIPTION HERE");
```

Does above function for setting Description takes array with store ids or is there another way around. Immediate help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I recomend you read the functions

```
_initProduct()
_initProductSave()
saveAction()
```

in

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
```

Which covers how Magento does it.

You can capture the POST data by creating a test product in the Magento admin area, pressing the save button and inspecting the POST data sent back to Magento (or by sticking a quick `var_dump` in `saveAction()` )